# Change display information (like name) of files from a shell extension for explorer.exe

Tags: c#, windows-shell

I'm currently working with a Chinese SMB server, on which almost all the company files are stored.
As the structure doesn't change, I'd like to be able to put a "label" on files, based on a rules (something that allow me to handle generated files, which includes dates for example).
I need only support for win7 and above, and I'd like my informations to be read from a text file rather than relying on some metadata or client's data.

So I thought of writting a shell extension to do the work. My problem is, that by looking at [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144067%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), I didn't find something that allow me to change the name. The best solution I've found so far is to go with [the infotip handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761359%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but I wondering if anyone has a better way to do this.

In short, it needs:

1) To be compatible with win7 (and above),

2) To be visible at first sight

3) To use a readonly fs

Comment: How much text do you need in your label? You might be able to change the icon?

Comment: Not much, as it is only "name translation". So under 255 char would be enough. For the icon, do you mean using [IExtractIcon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144122(v=vs.85).aspx) ? If so, I don't see any limitation, so I guess it would be okay.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant, either IExtractIcon or [IShellIconOverlayIdentifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761265%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Don't think an icon in "small icons", "list" or "details" view would big enough to display a 20+ character filename clearly, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After extensive research, I've found that the best way to do it is to write a [Shell Namespace extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144095%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

I'll be able to provide a virtual directory representing my server's structure, and translate the names the way I want.

This seems a little overkill though, but there's no other way to change the informations displayed as the display name is managed by an [IShellFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775075%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which provides it to an [IShellView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774834%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

One excellent source of informations I've found about it, and the most up to date so far, is [an article on Michael Edenfiled's blog](http://blog.kutulu.org/2012/01/com-interop-part-10-recapping-and.html)